# How to draw straight line between several frames with moving camera?

Tags: python, computer-vision, tracking, opticalflow, object-recognition

I am trying to get ball coordinates data from football (soccer) video. From technology that I have used I was able to determine ball coordinates. Example, 12 second video was divided into several frames and from each frame I should have got ball coordinates and save it to array which has following elements ["frame number" , "x coordinate", "y coordinate"]. But it did not recognized ball all the time. Particularly, I have ball coordinates from frame #7 (x and y) and do not have any data till frame #35. I want to add ball coordinates from frame #7 to #35 by drawing straight line between last coordinate (#35) and first (#7). The issue is that I cannot simply use vector calculation and draw line because video is not static. What I mean is that coordinate (x , y) in frame #7 and same (x,y) in frame #8 are very different since in between camera is moved.

How can I fill the lacking 22 frames with coordinates that will join ball from #7 frame with line to ball in #35 frame.

I hope you understand the problem.

Comment: sorry lacking 28 frames.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.